# Why does my .NET Console Application exit without running Main?

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application, program-entry-point

I just opened up the source code for a console application that was deployed a couple years ago to run twice a day as a windows scheduled task on our server (it updates something in the database). When it was deployed was running just fine, but now we need to make some code changes. I try to run it in Debug and the program won't even enter sub main. It hits the line

static void Main(string[] args) and just ends running. The console window disappears. I haven't heard from the clients that the production version isn't running, but when I check their servers I don't see the Event Log entries that I should (the app is supposed to write to the Event Log each time it runs)

Comment: What do you see in the Output window?

Comment: What version of .NET was it written for? What versions are running on the machines it is working on and failing on?

Comment: Do you see an exception in the debugger?

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010). The machine it's working on probably runs more than one version but I'm not sure.

Comment: I do not get an exception in the debugger. It just ends running completely.

Comment: I see this in the debugger
A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: Perhaps your debugger isn't configured to stop on first-chance exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a DLL issue.

If `Main()` uses types from an assembly that the JITter can't find, the program will die before hitting `Main()`.
This would also happen if the type containing `Main()` has fields of a type that couldn't be loaded.

It could also happen if that type's static constructor calls `Environment.FailFast()`.

Comment: It might be easier to debug if you create a second, empty class with its own Main method that simply calls the original Main in a try-catch block. Then set the second class as the startup class.

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen this occur if you don't have the correct version of .NET framework on the machine you're running the application on.
Perhaps you changed the target framework version when you recompiled it.

Comment: Check your app.config.  Look for this line:
supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=

Make sure whatever comes after "Version=" is legit for where you're running.